# Saving data into DB s considered Serialization?

Tags: c#, serialization

Serialization -> Convert an object to a binary representation that can be then written to Disk or write on a file..

Above is the basic definition of serialization that I know. But what does this really mean? I have a class in my application and I use this to get data from user and store it in Database. Does this mean I am using serializion here? Even storing the data is more like saving the state of the object, I can get the data and form the same object once again.

Can any one light me up with whats a real serialization? If serialization is not used what will be the result? Whats the difference between saving the data in a file and doing the serialization (to save the data) in a file.

Comment: I find that question interesting. Since 'they' talk about serialization being a binary form, I wonder what they think about the object being in-memory. Is an in-memory database using serialization as well? Grey area I'd say.

Comment: Exactly, but we do not use Serialization on the class data which we store it in DB!! This always is a difficult to understand whenever I come across Serialization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I doubt storing data in a database should be considered serialization. Even when you're storing the data coming from your object-oriented programming layer, actually you're translating objects into the relational world and viceversa. **This is called data-mapping**.

Perhaps you may argue *performing an `INSERT` is storing data in an interoperable format*. Not necessarily, since SQL is a domain-specific language to manage relational data, and you don't know how the data is actually stored either in memory or disk. SQL itself isn't a serialization format.

Since most databases are on disk, you can consider serialization the process of persisting database registers to disk in order to retrieve or alter them afterwards, and use RAM to optimize reads and writes without carrying the entire database to memory.

In the other hand, *serialization* can be done in binary or non-binary formats. For example, you can serialize an object into JSON, and JSON isn't a binary format. Also, XML it has been used as serialization format for years and it's not binary.

A good definition to *serialization* may be: **consider serialization when some in-memory object is turned into an interoperable representation that can be stored in disk or transmitted over the wire to easily get back it as in-memory object in any platform and language being capable of understanding the serialization format.**

Examples:

- A REST API sending a list of users as data-transfer objects serialized to JSON.
- An application lets user visually edit its configuration and settings. When UI needs to show current values, it will deserialize the configuration back to objects to bind them to the UI, and once the user presses <kbd>Save</kbd>, configuration gets serialized again to disk.
- An application provides its own backup. The backup can be the entire object graph serialized as JSON.

Comment: Hmmm.. In that case, I am saving an object data in a file (saving it as table format and not json/xml). I am transferring that file to other computer and using the same data file. I will write a logic so that I get the data and process it and create a new object. Is this Serialization as-well??

Comment: @MohanPrasath Why not? If you're turning your data into a file to get back running in other environment, you're serializing/deserializing your data, aren't you?

Comment: Fidemraizer: Now I get what you mean. Serialization is just using a common standard format to send and retrieve data across devices. So i  don't have to write an logic to process the data that is coming in. Since we have predefined standard logic we are using these techniques to send data across platforms. Thanks..:)

Comment: @MohanPrasath well not only across devices but also same device and same app. There are many use cases. You're welcome ;)

Comment: Fidemraizer: Yeah, but the standard is defined here already. Developer don't have to bother about how to send and process the data every time.